# How do I convert a kml file into an image using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, mpdf

I need to be able to convert my kml files into an image so I can use them on a pdf I'm generating using mpdf.  I am currently using the javascript api to display the kml map on my webpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Google Maps Image APIs:

> The Google Maps Image APIs make it easy to embed a static Google Maps image or Street View panorama into your web page, with no need for JavaScript.
>
> The APIs are as simple as constructing a URL with the information
>   about your image; once the URL is loaded from an image tag, Google
>   will create and return your map or Street View scene.

Then you can get an image instead of the javascript map with

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200">
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/)

Comment: The google map static image will not work for me since I am using a custom google map displaying a kml file.

Comment: Ok, try this: http://pierrerebours.com/blog/using-xsl-convert-kml-file-static-google-map-image

Comment: Thanks Asterisk.  I was able to parse the kml using php simplexml_load_file() and after some tweaking use the values as parameters in the static image url.